# i want to assign each alphabet with a value and want a method to return sum accordingly

Tags: c#

```
static void Main()
{
    int x = Program.char_value("cat");
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static int char_value(string user_input)
{
    char a = 'a';
    char c = 'c';
    char t = 't';
    int user_input_length = user_input.Length;
    int char_value = 0;
    if (user_input == "" && user_input_length <= 5)
    {
        foreach (char z in user_input)
        {
            if (z == a)
            {
                char_value = 1;
            }
            if (z == c)
            {
                char_value += 3;
            }
            if (z == t)
            {
                char_value += 20;
            }
        }
        return char_value;
    }
    return char_value;
}
```

Comment: People generally put the same amount of effort into answers, as the poster puts into their question.

Comment: 1) learn to format your code before posting it 2) What problems are you having with the code you posted?  Does it not work, does it throw an exception, is it just not pretty?

Comment: If you are working with `Chars 'a', 'b', 'c'` etc it would also make sense to name your variables better not by using single letters

Comment: it dont return a value

Comment: your if statement will prevent anything useful from happening

Comment: you are write DJ, but im not talking about conventions here, i want that code should return my desired value

Comment: than what i need to do

Comment: @RummyKhan What is your desired value? You need to explain what you want.

Comment: What do you mean "it dont return a value"? It should at least return 0. It's just not getting anything other than 0, because you need to check `if (user_input != ""`, not `if (user_input == ""` Your code currently only gets to the foreach loop if an empty string is passed, which is not what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply convert your `char` into an `int` instead?

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (char z in user_input.ToLower())
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(z) - 96; // ensures that 'a' has value 1, 'b' has value 2, etc.

return sum;
```

Comment: i didnot got that part charValues.add(convert.toint32(z) - 96);

Comment: Runny Khan try the code example that Nolonar has provided the only wat to get it is to try it step thru the code and understand why you are getting the results that you are getting.. show more effort `Rummy Khan`

Comment: @RummyKhan I don't understand your comment. Do you not understand what the line does, or does Visual Studio not accept it?

Comment: @RummyKhan I corrected a few errors in my code, sorry I was a little sloppy.

Comment: itx ok, i was also amazed to see the errors list..

Comment: @Nolonar, thanx man, it worked.... but again im confusing in charValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(z) - 96); thix part, here we can also use charValues.Add(int.Parse(z) - 96);, but why we wrote "- 96"..?? in here

Comment: @RummyKhan I made my code simpler (and more efficient). About the `- 96` part, it's because the value of `'a'` is `97` according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871.aspx so if you want `'a'` to be `1`, you have to subtract `96`

Comment: oh God, i never knew thix, thanx again bravo..

Comment: @RummyKhan Before I forget: The value of `'a'` (`97`) is not the same as the value of `'A'` (`65`), so maybe you want to convert your string to lower-case first `user_input.ToLower()`. Btw. if this is the answer you were looking for, don't forget to accept/upvote.

Comment: i was already thinking about that too..